# Recover deleted ports in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk

Is there any way to recover the physical send & receive ports once deleted without exporting the bindings?

Comment: I think, only option is to restore system to previous working state using checkpoints (if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you export the bindings the ports will not exist and so will not be exported. I think Bilal is correct - this data resides in the management database, so you would need to restore from a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is always have a binding file configuration for your application. Once your BizTalk applications are configured with correct send, receive ports, orchestration host etc make sure you back up your binding configuration using "Export Binding" option in BizTalk admin console.

In fact, in bigger projects binding files will be normally owned by deployment teams for various environments and you never create ports using admin console in real environments.

It will be bit overkill to restore your BizTalk databases, just get your ports back. I would rather create them manually again, even if the numbers are hight. Restoring databases requires special attention, if you do it wrong you will end up reconfiguring the whole environment which will be time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Saravana.
My 5c: you can import existed binding files and that will not remove ports that are not in the binding files. The import process works in "addition" mode.